# Why does this program automatically stop at 18?

Tags: batch-file

Filename: 1.bat

```
@echo off
cls
set /a a=%~n0+1
set /a b=%~n0*2
For /l %%c in (%a%,1,%b%) do type %~nx0 > %%c.bat
cls
echo Enter password:
set /p "Pass=>"
If not %pass%==tamaulipas_living_rock_cactus (
goto fail
)
exit /b

:fail
echo WRONG!
pause
For /f %%d in ('dir /a /b /on') do set f=%%d
call %f%
```

This program is just supposed to make a bunch of copies of itself inside whatever folder it's in, doubling each time the person gets the password wrong. When testing it, the program went to 16, then 18 and stopped. If it stopped at 32 or 16 that would make some sense as it is a power of two and perhaps something is capping it there, but why is 18, such a random number, the stopping point? And the weird thing is that running 18.bat does what it's supposed to, and same with 36, and 72, etc. The part that says:

```
For /f %%d in ('dir /a /b /on') do set f=%%d
call %f%
```

should run 18.bat, but instead it just refreshes the password prompt without making any new files.

I wanted to mess with my friend (who is bad with computers) with it and eventually tell him the password at like 512 or something.

Alternatively, I tried removing the password part and replacing it with

```
@echo off
cls
If %~n0==512 (
Exit /b
)
set /a a=%~n0+1
set /a b=%~n0*2
For /l %%c in (%a%,1,%b%) do type %~nx0 > %%c.bat
For /f %%d in ('dir /a /b /on') do set f=%%d
call %f%
```

But this one has the same weird result

Comment: `set f=%%` ?? You mean `set f=%%d` ?

Comment: @Stephan I think that's where I messed up maybe

Answer (score 1):

By changing :

```
If %~n0==512 (
Exit /b
)
```

to:

```
If %~n0==8 (
Exit /b
)
```

it worked correctly, but not for:

```
If %~n0==16 (
Exit /b
)
```

And then I realized the program looks for them sorted in name order, and the first digit is the first one that is processed, so the program would repeat 9.bat over and over again, which is why it ends at 18.

Sorting by date (which I originally didn't do in fear of the computer not being accurate to the nanosecond) fixed the problem